# How to Create List within SharePoint 2013 Apps?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-apps

I am developing `Apps` for `SharePoint 2013`. And I want to create Multiple list in My App Package *programmatically*.
It is like user inputs Name of list and when he clicks the Create Button the list with the same name should be created in my App not in SharePoint site.

I have created an `AutoHosted App` in which I have used Client Side Object Model technology.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: I have created the List Using Client Object Model. But All the list were being created in SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
When I was creating the `ContextToken` object in that I was passing the `SPHostUrl` of the request but instead of that I passed `SPAppWebUrl` So using that it get the token of the AppWebUrl and thus it created the list in my App not in SharePoint site.

Like bellow code:

```
var hostWeb = Page.Request["SPAppWebUrl"]; //This will get the URL of AppWeb not SharePoint site...

using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithContextToken(hostWeb, ContextToken, Request.Url.Authority))
{
     //Code for creating list or manipulating them...
     //This ClientContext is created for the AppWeb.
}
```

When I was searching the code for creating every time I was finding the `hostWeb` object is created using `SPHostUrl` Therefore I asked this question.
**Thank you everyone for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript Client Object Model to create the list in the App. There's a code example demonstrating how to do so here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListCRUD

Comment: Actually sir I have created list using that but it creates the list in SharePoint site not in My App.